# SFTP file upload in WCF service

Tags: wcf, upload, sftp

Can anyone help me out on how to implement file upload from mobile device to Dotnet service using SFTP process using WCF service or any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WCF` works on `HTTP` protocol with or without `SSL`.

`SFTP` works on `SSH` protocol with or without `SSL`.

`FTPS` works on `FTP` protocol using `SSL`.

First make sure what you exactly want to do and which protocol is suitable for your case.

If you are looking to transfer a file using `WCF` try to use *Stream* as input type and store it on a physical location on the disk.

Comment: I want to write a service to upload files using SFTP from mobile application. Can you please suggest me the best way to do this

Comment: did you even read my answer? for SFTP you need to create a client that connects to the SFTP server and uploads it. google